# Saving data from a dynamically generated HTML table/grid to a database

Tags: javascript, html, django

I'm developing a web application and one of the requirements is for the user to enter data into a dynamically-generated HTML grid/table. An admin user can log into the Django Admin interface and create some entries, which will represent the columns and rows of the grid, and then a dynamic grid is generated based on these values.  In this example, the admin user has entered "Store #1", Store #2", etc. as the rows, and "Chips", "Chocolates", and "Soda" as the columns. These rows and columns are then used to generate a grid which is rendered in a Django template by the code below:

```
<table class="tg">
<thead>
    <th rowspan="3"></th>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-title" colspan="4">Inventory</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    {% for i in items %}
      <td class="tg-column">{{ i }}</td>
    {% endfor %}
  </tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
{% for i in stores %}
  <tr>
      <td class="tg-column">{{ i }}</td>
    {% for i in items %}
      <td class="tg-cell"><input type="number" min="0" max="255" value="0"></td>
    {% endfor %}
  </tr>
 {% endfor %}

  <tr>
    <td class="tg-totals">Totals</td>
    {% for i in items %}
      <td class="tg-totals-values">0</td>
    {% endfor %}
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

The above code renders like this:

[image]

Visually, this is fine, but I can't for the life of me figure out how I'm supposed to save this form into a database table.  The thing here is that a user may review this entry in the future, and so it would need to be put "back" into the same grid as is seen here if ever loaded in the future.  I have no clue how to do this -- does each input field need to have its own "id=" field?  Is it even possible to do this with a truly dynamic grid?  What if there were 100 stores and 10 items per store?

Answer (score 0):

This depends on what is your database technology, if there is a JSON field (MySQL 5.7+ or a new version of Postgres) then it can be helpful as your model will look something like this

```
     class Data(models.Model):
           name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
           values = jsonfield()
```

Then you can store the name of each column as a key in the JSON field, this will give you the ability to add new columns on the fly as you can use the `get` function.

For saving the data, you need to write a JS code to convert the grid to a proper JSON object and send it over the request and on the backend, the view can load the JSON and save it to the database.

Also, the JS function can be smart to send only the updated rows to decrease the data size and request processing time needed.